# Prove that 1 + 1 is 1 with Formal Logic

Tags: lateral-thinking

**Puzzle:**

Prove that $1 + 1$ is $1$ using formal logic.

**Hint:**

> $1 + 0$ is $0$

**Hint 2 (edit):**

> No new definitions are required. The solution does have to do with the symbol + other actual (perhaps less formal) definitions.

Comment: Howw can yu explain that with "formal logic" but tagged as lateral thinking? I just thought thays ironic, but you probably have your own explanation.

Comment: @North There is definitely a reason. It's what makes this puzzle work.

Comment: Given that you have to go outside normal mathematics, there are endlessly many different solutions, each one just as good as the other, and no way to tell which answer is the correct one.

Comment: I’m thinking this is more a coding question where + is more of an ‘and’ so 1 and 1 is true (1) and 1 and 0 is false (0)

Comment: @AggieKidd That's what I was thinking. And I used "formal logic" because and is an operation in formal logic.

Comment: This is simply strange...

Answer (score 4):

I suspect there will be multiple answers to this, but here's one:

> Define the "+" operator to mean "the following number."

Then:

> 1 + 0 is 0
>  1 + 1 is 1

In fact,

> x + 0 is 0, for any x, and x + 1 is 1, for any x, etc.

Comment: Similar to my first thought. Formally define the + symbol as a multiplication operator.

Comment: @MattStevens that would also work - and it's perhaps simpler than mine :)

Comment: That's not exactly what I was thinking. No new definitions are required. The solution does have to do with the symbol + other actual (perhaps less formal) definitions.